What does "as it is written of him" refer to in Mark 9:13?
Reading the Gospel of Mark today I notice that this gospel (and none of the others) portrays Jesus as saying, when questioned as to why the scribes say that Elijah must come first:

I tell you that Elijah has come, and they did to him whatever they
pleased, as it is written of him [my emphasis].

My main question is what does "as it is written of him" refer to? The prophecy of Elijah's return comes from Mal. 4:4 but it says nothing about people doing to him as they please. Or is it the case that "as it is written" does not refer to persecution (of John, acting as Elijah), but to the fact that Malachi predicted his return?

In our day we would have it written in brackets

“But I tell you that Elijah has come, (and they did to him whatever they pleased), as it is written about him.””
‭‭Mark‬ ‭9‬:‭13‬ ‭

Thus the reference is about Malachi 4:5, that Elijah would be sent as a forerunner to prevent a curse on the land. Jesus acknowledges that indeed Elijah had come but that they did with him as they pleased. The order of the wording is throwing the reading off slightly.

“But I tell you that Elijah has come, as it is written about him, and they did to him whatever they pleased.””
‭‭Mark‬ ‭9‬:‭13‬ ‭


Yes... it took me a while to get over the literal meaning, which would be that it had been prophesied that Elijah would be rejected.

I checked all the other resources including the apocrypha and I didnt see a reference to them doing whatever they wanted with him.
